# Javascript await is a reserved word?

Tags: javascript

I think I am doing everything correctly. But the program is showing "`await is a reserved keyword`" in `signin` function. Here is the code:

```
import axios from "axios";
const signin = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    console.log("Sign in function called");
    const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.baseURL}/auth/signin`, {
      username,
      password
    });
    console.log(res.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const logout = () => {
  // remove user from local storage to log user out
  localStorage.removeItem("jobmanager_user");
};

export const userService = {
  signin,
  logout
};
```

Comment: which editor you are using?

Comment: @brk VsCode. This is a part of vuejs project.

Comment: It shouldn't give you that warning, you have used it correctly.

Comment: Odds are you are using an older version of node that doesn't recognize `await`.

Comment: @meagar you marked as a duplicate but they are different questions...

Comment: issue may be with babel
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6720

Comment: Rather than using a function expression, try using a function statement. That will remove the ambiguity of where that identifier (`signin`) actually points.